# Stripping comments from SQL using Ruby

Tags: ruby

I want to turn this:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ABC;
  --My comments
  SELECT 1 AS A
SQL
```

Into this:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ABC;
  SELECT 1 AS A
SQL
```

This is what I have:

```
sql = sql.split("\n").reject { |i| i.strip.start_with?("--") }.join("\n")
```

I was hoping for some other built-in method of doing it if possible, one that would cover multi-line `/*...*/` comments as well.  Any ideas?

Comment: To strip comments from *arbitrary* SQL, you will need a parser, not just regexes. For example, `SELECT "foo \" /* bar */"` should be preserved as-is, but most regex solutions would mangle the string literal. To handle these situations, either [find an existing SQL parser for Ruby](https://www.google.com/search?q=Ruby+SQL+parser), or write your own that only parses constructs that affect comments, using something like [Parslet](http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/). Whatever parser you use, process the tree to remove only comment nodes, and then re-convert the tree back into SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You're making it too hard:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ABC;
  --My comments
  SELECT 1 AS A
SQL

sql.lines.reject{ |l| l.lstrip[/^--/] }.join # => "  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ABC;\n  SELECT 1 AS A\n"
```

There's no need to split on `"\n"` since the line-breaks are useful. Instead, `lines` does a similar thing only it returns the line with the trailing line-break intact. `lstrip` makes it easy to see if  `--` is the first thing on the line. `join` converts the resulting array back into a string, and the trailing line-breaks go along for the ride.

Trying to strip a multi-line block comment that way is a lot more difficult, so I'd take a different path. After removing single line comments I'd do something like:

```
sql = <<-SQL
  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ABC;
  /* 
  My comments
  */
  SELECT 1 AS A
SQL

stripped = sql.lines.reject{ |l|
  if l['/*'] .. l['*/']
    true
  else
    false
  end  
}
stripped # => ["  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ABC;\n", "  SELECT 1 AS A\n"]
```

The magic is `..`, which is AKA the "flip-flop" operator, and is perfect for this sort of situation, where you want to find the beginning of something, and then the end of it. What happens is when `l['/*']` finds a match, `..` remembers that there was a match and begins returning true. Once `l['*/']` matches, `..` begins returning false again. It seems like

```
l['/*'] .. l['*/']
```

would work by itself, but Ruby needs to see a conditional test, like `if`, to know whether `..` is a flip-flop or a range operator. It's an unfortunate collision between the two uses of `..` and a lot of people shy away from it, but that's not a good reason to avoid it.

An interesting discussion regarding this use of `..` is at "[Remove flip-flops in 2.0](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5400)". I personally disagree with any move to get rid of the operator as its functionality is very useful for this sort of situation, and replacing it with pure Ruby code seems messier, but perhaps that is because I've used it for so long in both Ruby and Perl.